# Need to intercept Onchange event of an output field with inlineEdit in VF page

Tags: jquery, inputfield, inlineeditsupport

I have a requirement where I need to populate a set of fields on the basis of selected dependent list picklist value (in Inline edit). I am aware that there is no straightforward way of handling any events on Output tags. I also know that inlineedit functionality creates hidden input behind the scenes. I have tried using JQuery but still not able to intercept the DOM event. CAn anyone help me with that please, I am not a pro in Javascript/Jquery. Following is the code snippet:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery)}"/>  


<script type="text/javascript"> 

function oppStageChangeResult(){

$('[id$=fs_opp_source_cat_details]').change(function(){

    console.log('Stage Changed');

})


}

function displayAlert(){
    alert('Stage Changed');
}


   $(document).ready(function() {
       alert('Ready Again');
      $('.wrapperClass :hidden').change(function(e) {
          alert('Hidden input was changed');
      });
  });
```

```
<apex:form >

        <apex:outputpanel >
            <apex:actionstatus id="status">
                <apex:facet name="start">
                    <div class="waitingSearchDiv" id="el_loading" style="background-color: #fbfbfb; height: 100%;opacity:0.65; width:100%;"> 
                        <div class="waitingHolder" style="top:40%;">
                            <img class="waitingImage" src="/img/loading.gif" title="Please Wait..." />
                            <span class="waitingDescription">Loading...</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionstatus>
        </apex:outputpanel>            



<apex:pageBlock id="displayPB">
       <apex:inlineEditSupport >
   <apex:pageBlockSection >

        <apex:outPutField id="fs_opp_stage_details" value="{!opportunity.stagename}" >
        </apex:outPutField>

               <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="wrapperClass">

                   <apex:outputLabel value="Opportunity Source"/>

         <apex:outPutField id="fs_opp_source_details" value="{!opportunity.Opportunity_Source__c}" >

        </apex:outputField>

               </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


       <apex:outPutField id="fs_opp_source_cat_details" value="{!opportunity.Source_Category__c}" >
        </apex:outPutField>        

         <apex:outPutField value="{!opportunity.PRY_Name_of_Referrer__c}" rendered="{!if(opportunity.Source_Category__c=='Newspaper',true,false)}" />

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:inlineEditSupport>


</apex:pageBlock>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, you have to use partial Id selector to find the element. Here is an example, where I have attached onchange event to all elements inside `apex:pageBlockSection`. Based on the target Id of the event you can find the input element.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:includeScript value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"/>    
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" id="editButton" value="Edit"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="saveButton" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:inlineEditSupport >
                <apex:pageBlockSection id="mysection">
                    <apex:outputField id="lastname" value="{!contact.lastname}"/>
                    <apex:outputField id ="accname" value="{!contact.accountId}"/>
                    <apex:outputField id ="phone" value="{!contact.phone}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:inlineEditSupport>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("div[id$='mysection'] :hidden").change(function(evt) {
                if($(evt.target).attr("id").indexOf("lastname")!=-1){
                    alert("Last Name Changed");
                }else if($(evt.target).attr("id").indexOf("accname")!=-1){
                    alert("Account Name Changed");
                }else if($(evt.target).attr("id").indexOf("phone")!=-1){
                    alert("Phone No Changed");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>    
</apex:page>
```

Comment: But this does not seem to work with dependent picklist withing inlineedit.